# Clean Instantiation of a Vector in the Base Class

Tags: c++, class, c++11, vector

I'm working on code in C++11 and part of the code related to class construction and vector values has gotten out of hand. How can I make this more concise?

My work is related to version and have created a vector of version numbers of type `std::vector<uint16_t>` to hold an array of values to represent the version of format `1.0.0.25`. I would like all classes to have a Version so I placed this in the base class. The children then inherit for `Base` and instantiate the version.

Currently, my code has a Version class, a Base class, and a Child class. The developer will hardcode the version in by setting the value in a define variable in the Child class. I would like that to be easy to see and read.  My issue is that the part where the Child class passes the value is currently very ugly and I'm hoping to make it more concise and readable.

The code is:

```
#include <vector>

namespace CodeStuff
{
namespace VersionStuff
{


typedef uint16_t VersionType;

class Version
{

public:
    Version(const std::vector<VersionType> & aNumbers, const VersionType aType = -1)
    {
        numbers_ = aNumbers;
        type_ = aType;
    }
private:
    std::vector<VersionType> numbers_;
    VersionType type_;
};

} // end namespace VersionStuff
} // end namespace CodeStuff

class Base
{
public:
    Base(const CodeStuff::VersionStuff::Version & aVersion) : version_(aVersion)
    {
    }

    const CodeStuff::VersionStuff::Version getVersion() const {return version_;}

private:
    const CodeStuff::VersionStuff::Version version_;
};


#define CHILD_VERSION {1, 0, 0, 25}

class Child : public Base
{
public:
    Child() : Base(CodeStuff::VersionStuff::Version{std::vector<CodeStuff::VersionStuff::VersionType>{CHILD_VERSION}}) {}
};



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Child myChild();
}
```

And my issue is that while I like have an easy way to see the Version as in `#define CHILD_VERSION {1, 0, 0, 25}`, the constructor call is incredibly ugly:

```
 Child() : Base(CodeStuff::VersionStuff::Version{std::vector<CodeStuff::VersionStuff::VersionType>{CHILD_VERSION}}) {}
```

I would like to do this:

```
Child() : Base(CHILD_VERSION) {}
```

But in XCode this results in an error of "No Matching Constructor for initialization of type Base". Because this is valid syntax:

```
std::vector<uint16_t> v({1, 0 ,0 ,25});
```

I'm unsure why the short `Base(CHILD_VERSION)` doesn't work in c++11.

How can I shorten this?

Comment: Why don't you use a struct with the 4 values?

Comment: @manni66 In the full version, the list can be of arbitrary length and handles a wider range of functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dealt with something very like this recently, and rather than passing around a vector, I used `std::initializater_list` as my route to simple constant version numbers.  Here is an example:

```
class Version {
  std::vector<unsigned> version;
 public:
  Version(const std::string & s);
  Version(std::initializer_list<unsigned> list) : version(list) {}
  bool operator== (const Version & other) const {
    return version == other.version;
  }
  bool operator< (const Version & other) const {
    return version < other.version;
  }
};
```

Here a Version can be created like this:

```
Version v{1, 0 ,0 ,25};
```

You can make your base class have a `std::initializer_list` constructor as well, and pass it on to your `version_` object.

Comment: Why won't the compiler just convert my initializer list to a vector like normal? I'm think of using this and keeping the constructor with a vector for code already using a vector.

Comment: @Steve code is only allowed to do one implicit constructor. The vector constructor that allows you to do {1, 2, 3, 4} is a constructor that takes an initializer list, but there is no vector constructor that takes 4 parameters. The compiler isn't allowed to say "I expect this to be a vector, and vector has an initializer list constructor that matches the parameter passed, so I'm going to convert the arguments to an initializer list and then to a vector" - it's the fact that it takes 2 hops to go from where you're at to where you want to be that bites you.